# How can I delete useless strings by index from a Pandas DataFrame defining a function?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a DataFrame, namely 'traj', as follow:

```
   x   y   z
0  5   3   4
1  4   2   8
2  1   1   7
3  Some string here
4  This is spam
5  5   7   8
6  9   9   7
... #continues repeatedly a lot with the same strings here in index 3 and 4
79 4   3   3
80 Some string here
```

I'm defining a function in order to delete useless strings positioned in certain index from the DataFrame. Here is what I'm trying:

```
def spam(names,df): #names is a list composed, for instance, by "Some" and "This" in 'traj'
    return df.drop(index = ([traj[(traj.iloc[:,0] == n)].index for n in names]))
```

But when I call it it returns the error:

```
traj_clean = spam(my_list_of_names, traj)
...
KeyError: '[(3,4,...80)] not found in axis'
```

If I try alone:

```
traj.drop(index = ([traj[(traj.iloc[:,0] == 'Some')].index for n in names]))
```

it works.

Comment: Call the function using `df.apply()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it in a different way:

```
df = traj[~traj[:].isin(names)].dropna()
```

Where names is a list of the terms you wish to delete.

df will contain only rows without these terms

Comment: Thanks, it works great! Just because now I'm curious, do you have idea how to solve in the way asked anyway? I think could be useful :)